# Creating a simple Game score manager in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a scoreboard in visual basic that allows the user to type in a certain number and it adds to the score every time.

[This is the kind of layout I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atlRI.png)

There are two teams, when a user enters the number in the text box (white one) it will comeup on the grey textbox above, and it will add every time the user types in a number.

Also, how can I display a warning message when a user enters a invalid data? EG - a letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple XMlserialize for storing score values outside of application .Every time when you open application you can read you object and every time when you exit you can store your objects  .Read more : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316730
Your simple serializable class will be such :

```
<Serializable()>
Class UsersList

        Public Property members As List(Of User)
        Sub New()
            members = New List(Of User)
        End Sub

        Public Sub add(user As User)
            If IsNothing(members) = False Then
                members.Add(user)
            End If

        End Sub
    End Class
    Class User
        Public scores As List(Of Single)
        Public Property name As String
        Sub New()
            scores = New List(Of Single)
        End Sub

        Public Sub add(score As Single)
            If IsNothing(scores) = False Then
                scores.Add(score)
            End If

        End Sub

    End Class

And For user input you can do two ways :

        'Displaying warning when it is not valid float number
    'works for floating numbers too
            Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles YouTextbox1.TextChanged,YourTextbox2.TextChanged
                Dim cheked As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
                If IsNothing(cheked) = False Then
                    Dim f As Single
                    If Single.TryParse(cheked.Text, f) = False Then
                        MessageBox.Show("Warning .Please enter valid number")

                    End If

                End If
            End Sub
        'not allow user enter to type wrong keys
         Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox.KeyPress
              'Disallow user type anything besides numbers 
                If e.KeyChar < CChar("0") Or e.KeyChar > CChar("9") Then
                    e.Handled = True
                End If
            End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the comment.

I am not very familiar with XMSerialize you mentioned, I simply wanted an application which adds the inserted number in the textbox to be added to another textbox.

So textbox1 has a default of "0" and a user enters a number in textbox 2 (integer) then presses the button and the value in textbox 2 gets added to textbox 1.

Comment: then for your case it be such :If Single.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, f) =true then sum+=f TextBox1.Text=sum.ToString() TextBox1.Text="0" ... Did you want such way ?And in my previous answer u can find simple game score manager and input number validation warning .

Answer (score 0):

This will work for positive integers only:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Score1 As Integer = 0
    Private score2 As Integer = 0

    Public Const GWL_STYLE As Integer = (-16)
    Public Const ES_NUMBER As Integer = &H2000

    Public Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" _
        (ByVal handle As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer

    Public Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" _
        (ByVal handle As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer, ByVal dwNewLong As Integer) As Integer

    Public Sub SetNumbersOnlyTextBox(ByVal TB As TextBox)
        SetWindowLong(TB.Handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(TB.Handle, GWL_STYLE) Or ES_NUMBER)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SetNumbersOnlyTextBox(txtScore1)
        SetNumbersOnlyTextBox(txtScore1)
        DisplayScores()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAddScore1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddScore1.Click
        If txtScore1.Text.Trim.Length > 0 Then
            Score1 = Score1 + CInt(txtScore1.Text)
            DisplayScores()
            txtScore1.Clear()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAddScore2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddScore2.Click
        If txtScore2.Text.Trim.Length > 0 Then
            score2 = score2 + CInt(txtScore2.Text)
            DisplayScores()
            txtScore2.Clear()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DisplayScores()
        lblScore1.Text = Score1
        lblScore2.Text = score2
    End Sub

End Class
```